# Product discount percentage is not showing

Tags: onepage-checkout, discount

I've added the following code to the checkout page (item.phtml).

```
$_regularPrice = $_product->getPrice(); 
$_finalPrice = $_product->getFinalPrice();
if($_finalPrice < $_regularPrice):
    $special_percent = ceil(100 - (( 100/$_regularPrice ) * $_finalPrice )); echo $special_percent.'%'; else: echo '0%'; 
endif;
```

This code is showing proper percentage if I add special price to the product. But it is not working if I add Shopping Cart Pricing Rule. The output is always 0% if I add a Shopping Cart Pricing Rule, is there a way to do the same for Shopping Cart Pricing Rule?

Thanks.

Comment: Try to re-apply the price rules

Comment: Check the values for `$_regularPrice` and `$_finalPrice`

Comment: @Marius Both are giving the same amount.

Comment: @user3154108 It doesn't worked

Comment: This means that the problem is somewhere else. Maybe the catalog or shopping cart rules expired.

Comment: Thanks @Marius I've checked the expiry of the cart rule and everything is fine. I'm checking what went wrong.

Comment: @Marius I found the issue, the discount percentage is working if I add special price to the product. It is now working for pricing rule. Is there a way to implement the same for cart pricing rules?

Comment: This looks like a totally different question. Or at least update this question with what you found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Final price does not respect discount.  Because final price is the PRODUCT attribute, and discount is the CART ITEM attribute. Just use the `$item`, not `$product`.

discount: `$item->getDiscountAmount()`

original price: `$item->getCalculationPrice()`;